# Single class maps to two table join

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

looking at an existing NHibernate implementation that maps a single class to two database tables that are joined. The current functionality is read-only. The table join is actually hidden away via a readonly view and it's the view that's referred to in the NHibernate mapping.  Works fine for readonly behaviour. Except I need to add Insert, Update, Delete behaviour and only one of the tables needs to be inserted/updated/deleted.  How best to do this? I can take readonly off the view of course, I could replicate the join in the NHibernate mapping, but how do I tell NHibernate that insert/update/delete affects one table only?

Thanks DC

Answer (score 0):

You can map to a view instead of a table, then define custom sql for your inserts, updates and deletes.
I would recommend calling a stored procedure.

See the docs: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-cud

I've used this technique quite a lot and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the update and insert attributes on the [property mappings](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping/1nr4enxv3dpeq/8#5%282E%291%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Mapping_declaration) to false and they will be excluded from updates and inserts:

```
<property name="MyProperty" update="false" insert="false" />
```

Keep in mind that your view will need to have a single primary key defined to enable updates or inserts.